# How to implament teacher student functionality into django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Hi im working on a school project. I am supposed to make a teacher control panel that lets the teacher group students and stuff. How do i do such thing? Is there anything implamented in django. Also i cant just use the admin panel build into django because it should be a admin more of a like moderator. Hopefully you have some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Django will not offer any "teacher student" functionality, also this a very vague question as the functionality you need might be limited to the grouping but without any more information it's hard to give an actual answer.

You might try and look for some Django projects that implement some quiz kinda stuff like: [django-schools](https://github.com/suhailvs/django-schools). A quick google search will probably give you a few projects to look at.

And finally, you can actually give limited access to the Django admin to some users with the Django built-in permissions, so you could definitely use the Django admin interface for simple (and not so simple) apps.